# How to capture if a button in a table is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table of buttons

```
<table>
    <tr><input type="button" id="aaa1"></tr>
    <tr><input type="button" id="aaa2"></tr>
    etc
</table>
```

I would like capture when button is clicked, so I've written this code:

```
$('table').on('click', "[id^='aaa']", function(event){
    $(this)....
});
```

I think the problem is that this code is repeated for all the buttons, but I just wanna capture the button that I click. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What's wrong with `$(this)`?

Comment: the code is repeated for all button in my page. I wanna that is repeat one time only for the button that I clicked!

Comment: why don't assign a common class to those `inputs` and do `$('.yourclass').on('click', function(){...});`

Comment: @MIRACLE what you want to capture? please tell me.

Comment: Please use td inside tr.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You code isn't working because you have no table cells inside your table rows.

> I think the problem is that this code is repeated for all the buttons

This is not the case, the below example should show this.

I would continue using the deferred method you are currently using because it only adds one listener to the page instead of several for each of the buttons, however I would change it slightly to catch `type=button`, as shown below:

```js
$('table').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function(event) {
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" id="aaa1" value="B1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" id="aaa2" value="B2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("table input[type='button']").on('click', function(event) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: This will apply a click listener to each and every button. If the OP has lots of them it will be slow, and if the OP is generating them dynamically it won't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buttons").on("click",function(){
        var value = $(this).attr("value");
        alert(value + " is clicked");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><input type="button" id="aaa1" value="button1" class="buttons"></tr>
    <tr><input type="button" id="aaa2" value="button2" class="buttons"></tr>
    etc
</table>
```

Comment: You can't directly add DOM element inside tr

Comment: He was not asking for that Mr. -_- He was asking for jQuery and I told him

Comment: @ShehrozSheikh bipashant is correct. You answer simply gets around the problem, rather than fixing it.

Answer (score -1):

You can't directly add element inside tr.Use the td inside tr and add the element inside the tr

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("table input[type='button']").click(function() {
      alert('Button with id = "'+ this.id +'" is clicked');
      console.log(this);

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><td><input type="button" id="aaa1"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="button" id="aaa2"></td></tr>
</table>
```